# emacs --daemon doesn't successfully start the server

Tags: linux, emacs, daemon

I am attempting to set up a systemd daemon for emacs in NixOS.
When I added a systemd unit, I noticed that it was continually restarting over and over again.

I discovered that this was because when I ran `emacs --daemon`, it would show all the initialization and then return, but when I ran `ps -e | grep emacs`, nothing would show up, so I assume that it forked a background process that somehow failed. The output from `emacs --daemon` is below.

How can I either get `emacs --daemon` to not fail after forking, or at least figure out how to debug the forked process?

```
Warning: due to a long standing Gtk+ bug
http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85715
Emacs might crash when run in daemon mode and the X11 connection is unexpectedly lost.
Using an Emacs configured with --with-x-toolkit=lucid does not have this problem.
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/core/core-load-paths.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/core/core-load-paths.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.spacemacs...
Loading /home/olynch/.spacemacs...done
(Spacemacs) Warning: Cannot find font "Hack"!
Mark set
Mark set
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/.cache/spacemacs-buffer.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/.cache/spacemacs-buffer.el (source)...done
Mark set
Mark set
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+distribution/spacemacs/config.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+distribution/spacemacs-base/funcs.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+distribution/spacemacs-base/funcs.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+distribution/spacemacs-base/config.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+distribution/spacemacs-base/config.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+distribution/spacemacs-base/keybindings.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+distribution/spacemacs-base/keybindings.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+distribution/spacemacs/config.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/syntax-checking/config.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/syntax-checking/config.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/emacs-lisp/config.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/emacs-lisp/config.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+source-control/git/config.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+source-control/git/config.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/markdown/config.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/markdown/config.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/org/config.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/org/config.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/shell/config.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/shell/config.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/haskell/config.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/haskell/config.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/clojure/funcs.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/clojure/funcs.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/clojure/config.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/clojure/config.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/c-c++/config.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/c-c++/config.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/nixos/config.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/nixos/config.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+window-management/eyebrowse/config.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+window-management/eyebrowse/config.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/rust/funcs.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/rust/funcs.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/rust/config.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/rust/config.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/latex/funcs.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/latex/funcs.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/latex/config.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/latex/config.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/auto-completion/funcs.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/auto-completion/funcs.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/auto-completion/config.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/auto-completion/config.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/spell-checking/config.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/spell-checking/config.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+distribution/spacemacs-base/packages.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+distribution/spacemacs-base/packages.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+distribution/spacemacs/packages.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+distribution/spacemacs/packages.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/syntax-checking/packages.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/syntax-checking/packages.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/emacs-lisp/packages.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/emacs-lisp/packages.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+source-control/git/packages.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+source-control/git/packages.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/markdown/packages.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/markdown/packages.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/org/packages.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/org/packages.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/org/extensions.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/org/extensions.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/shell/packages.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/shell/packages.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+source-control/version-control/packages.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+source-control/version-control/packages.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/haskell/packages.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/haskell/packages.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/clojure/packages.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/clojure/packages.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/c-c++/packages.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/c-c++/packages.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/nixos/packages.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/nixos/packages.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/floobits/packages.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/floobits/packages.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/restclient/packages.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/restclient/packages.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/sql/packages.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/sql/packages.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/sql/extensions.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/sql/extensions.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+window-management/eyebrowse/packages.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+window-management/eyebrowse/packages.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/rust/packages.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/rust/packages.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/private/writeroom/packages.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/private/writeroom/packages.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/latex/packages.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/latex/packages.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/latex/extensions.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/latex/extensions.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/agda/extensions.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/agda/extensions.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/auto-completion/packages.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/auto-completion/packages.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/spell-checking/packages.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/spell-checking/packages.el (source)...done
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/deft/packages.el (source)...
Loading /home/olynch/.emacs.d/layers/deft/packages.el (source)...done
(Spacemacs) Warning: Agda not detected, be sure that Agda binaries are available in your PATH or check the installation instructions in the README file.
The variable evil-jumper-file is obsolete.  Persistence is done with savehist now.
Truncate long lines enabled

Starting new Ispell process /run/current-system/sw/bin/aspell with default dictionary...
Spacemacs is ready.
Restarting server
```

Comment: Have you tried `services.emacs.enable = true;`? It's suggested [in the NixOS manual](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#idm140737315656960).